# Placing Images and Text in Specific (Absolute) Locations Using iTextSharp

Tags: c#, itext

I am generating a PDF using iTextSharp and there is dynamic content in the middle of the page which is pushing the bottom part of my PdfPTable down too far. Sometimes even off the bottom of the page onto another page.

Would it be possible to position the bottom PdfPTable in a way that it would not get pushed down when the table above it needs more vertical space?

Comment: Are you familiar with the `WriteSelectedRows()` method?

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - I will look into it and get back to you. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: @BrunoLowagie - With the help of this post (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9864525/header-footer-and-large-tables-with-itextsharp), I almost have it working. Since there is no simple example in C# for using WriteSelectedRows(), I would like to post some basic sample code when I am done. Should I add that as an answer to my own question?

Comment: There should be a C# example here: http://tinyurl.com/itextsharpIIA2C04 but yes, it's always a good idea to post a small sample here fur further reference and accept that answer. It will be helpful for other people experiencing the same problem, and it will be helpful for me when I need to answer a similar question in the future.

Comment: I found one that uses WriteSelectedRows(), I will take a look today and see how that goes. (http://sourceforge.net/p/itextsharp/code/HEAD/tree/book/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextExamplesWeb/iTextInAction2Ed/Chapter04/PdfCalendar.cs)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution.

Views\Home\Index.cshtml:

```
<h2>Create PDF</h2>

@Html.ActionLink("Create the PDF", "CreatePDF", "Home")

</div>
```

HomeController.cs:

```
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        return View();
    }

    public FileStreamResult CreatePDF()
    {
        Stream fileStream = GeneratePDF();
        HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "inline; filename=MyPDF.pdf");

        var fileStreamResult = new FileStreamResult(fileStream, "application/pdf");
        return fileStreamResult;
    }

    private Stream GeneratePDF()
    {
        var rect = new Rectangle(288f, 144f);
        var document = new Document(rect, 10, 10, 10, 10);
        document.SetPageSize(PageSize.LETTER.Rotate());

        MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        PdfWriter pdfWriter = PdfWriter.GetInstance(document, memoryStream);
        document.Open();


        ////////////////////////
        //Place Image in a Specific (Absolute) Location
        ////////////////////////
        Image myImage = Image.GetInstance(Server.MapPath("../Content/BI_logo_0709.png"));
        myImage.SetAbsolutePosition(45, 45);
        //[dpi of page]/[dpi of image]*100=[scale percent]
        //72 / 200 * 100 = 36%
        //myImage.ScalePercent(36f);
        myImage.ScalePercent(36f);
        document.Add(myImage);



        ////////////////////////
        //Place Text in a Specific (Absolute) Location
        ////////////////////////

        //Create a table to hold everything
        PdfPTable myTable = new PdfPTable(1);
        myTable.TotalWidth = 200f;
        myTable.LockedWidth = true;

        //Create a paragraph with the text to be placed
        BaseFont bfArialNarrow = BaseFont.CreateFont(Server.MapPath("../Content/ARIALN.ttf"), BaseFont.CP1252, BaseFont.EMBEDDED);
        var basicSmaller = new Font(bfArialNarrow, 10);
        var myString = "Hello World!" +
                            Environment.NewLine +
                            "Here is more text." +
                            Environment.NewLine +
                            "Have fun programming!";
        var myParagraph = new Paragraph(myString, basicSmaller);

        //Create a cell to hold the text aka paragraph
        PdfPCell myCell = new PdfPCell(myParagraph);
        myCell.Border = 0;

        //Add the cell to the table
        myTable.AddCell(myCell);

        //Add the table to the document in a specific (absolute) location
        myTable.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 550, 80, pdfWriter.DirectContent);




        pdfWriter.CloseStream = false;
        document.Close();
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        return memoryStream;
    }
```